# syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input <h1>Hello, Rails!</h1> ^

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This should be an easy easy one as I'm new to ROR but I've tried to fix the error but just not finding it. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be great. I'm using Nitrous cloud hosting but that should not be the source of the problem. These are the steps on the tutorial:

> This will create the welcome controller with an index action defined.
>   Next lets edit app/views/welcome/index.html.erb, and delete all of the
>   code and replace it with the following:
>
> ```
> <h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
> <%= link_to "My Blog", controller: "posts" %>
> ```
>
> Let's setup the route to the homepage, and add the posts resource.
>   Open the file config/routes.rb and replace the text with the
>   following:
>
> ```
> Blog::Application.routes.draw do
>   resources :posts
>   root "welcome#index"
> end
> ```

Then when I start up the server to test it come's up with this:

```
/home/action/blog/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected '<' <h1>Hello, Rails!</h1> ^ /home/action/blog/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input <h1>Hello, Rails!</h1> ^
```

I know it's something stupid huh?

Comment: Post the welcome_controller.rb content

Comment: Please post code for welcome_controller.rb.

Comment: I was hoping the header would'nt actually show up like that. anyway it's <h1>hello, rails!</h1>

Comment: since it's saying the `<h1>` is unexpected, obviously the error is somwhere BEFORE wherever you've got that html.

Comment: <h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
<%= link_to "My Blog", controller: "posts" %> .... hey, like this but on seperate lines

Comment: You appear to be putting markup inside your controller. That's not where your markup goes. You need to start from the beginning with whatever Rails tutorial you're following and pay attention to the paths, because replacing the content of your *controller* with markup is *very* wrong.

Comment: Ok.. is markup the bits inside the <%=.... %>?

Answer (score 1):

Markup goes in your views, in `app/views`. Your controller should contain **Ruby code** for definining your controller. Something along the lines of

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

end
```

Comment: Make sure that the HTML is in a `.erb` file within `app/views/welcome`. It seems like the `<h1>` is actually in the controller file.

Comment: Hi thanks. Yes I had put it in the wrong one. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your welcome_controller.rb if you do not already have it:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
end
```

and add this to your index.html.erb (found in apps>views>welcome):

```
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
```

Comment: Hey thanks. ok so i wrote that back in and now this comes up: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant WelcomeController